# Back end scheduled script to connect to the DocuSign API using JWT

Tags: php, docusignapi

**My Aim**

Our web server will run a back end scheduled script to connect to the DocuSign API and send an envelope to a recipient using a template.

There's an excellent PHP [script on this page](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client), which does exactly what I want.  From what I understand, although this works in the sandbox, it won't work in production because we need to use OAuth and this example uses Legacy Header Authentication.

I looked at the various OAuth methods and picked JSON Web Token (JWT) bearer grant and I coded an working example using the library found [here](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt)  The access token only lasts for a set number of hours.  When it expires I am taken to a login screen and have to manually log into my DocuSign account to allow consent.  This is a back end script which needs to connect to the API without any user intervention.

So my question is how should this be done or is it possible to disable the manual login?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this? [Obtaining consent](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent) it seems that in order to grant permanent consent you'll have to have "Admin consent for internal applications", so that you are not redirected every time the JWT token expires.

Cheers.

Comment: Aghh.  I hadn't seen that so thanks for the link.  That functionality seems to be disabled for Sandbox demo accounts and the page says "Note: The Organization Admin feature is not enabled for all accounts. Please contact your DocuSign sales representative if you need to enable Organization Admin. "

Comment: Open a case with DocuSign Support: https://support.docusign.com
Provide your Demo account ID and request 'Allow Organization' be enabled for your sandbox account.

Comment: To grant consent to a single "system user" (eg "HR Department") user that will be impersonated via JWT, it is often easier to use Individual Consent. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain consent either through the Admin (Blanket) process or via the Individual Consent process.

For your use case of a single user that will be impersonated, individual consent is best. The process is:

1. Set up a `Redirect URI' for your integration key (client id). This is done via the DocuSign Admin tool. You can use https://www.docusign.com as the redirect uri or any other web site. It doesn't matter.
2. Go to a web browser and enter the following url:

   https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI

(For production, use https://account.docusign.com)

You need to login to DocuSign as the user that your app will be impersonating.

In the browser, you then agree to the consent request.

Then, back at your system integration application, your JWT Grant request should work fine with no `Consent Required` error.

If you want to use Admin (Blanket) Consent, contact DocuSign support to have Org admin capabilities added to your Developer Sandbox (demo) account.